# How to set events programmatically and create event popup with our own fields

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have Kendo UI timeline view controller and I want to set events from a different datasource, which will be a JavaScript array. I tried to set array to kendoScheduler datasource but event was not bound to the controller and when I double click on timeline it gives an event popup which has unwanted fields which I can't remove. Please find the sample below.

http://dojo.telerik.com/@lilan123/UPuDE/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this

```
var scheduler = $("#schedulerTimeLine").data("kendoScheduler");
var dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
  data: WorkPlanElementList
});
scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
```